# how to use javascript's regex to match the second number?

Tags: javascript, regex

this is my string.

```
var id = "timesheet_entries_attributes_0_entry_overtimes_attributes_0_code_id"
```

question is  I want to replace the last zero with another number.

the zero's position is always change. But there are only two zeros in the string. And they can't be together.

such as :

var num = "2";
    ("timesheet_entries_attributes_0_entry_overtimes_attributes_0_code_id").replace(/\d/,num);

but it always replace the first zero.

SoS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
id.replace (/(\d+)(?=\D+$)/, '2')
```

This version replaces the LAST number in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Just a different way to solve:

```
var id = "timesheet_entries_attributes_0_entry_overtimes_attributes_0_code_id",
    matchIndex = 1,
    replace = 300,
    count = -1;

id = id.replace(/\d+/g, function(number) {
    count++;
    return (count == matchIndex) ? replace : number;
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/eMgy6/1/)

Comment: And how to replace the second number?

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = "timesheet_entries_attributes_0_entry_overtimes_attributes_0_code_id";
var num_replace = 5;
id = id.replace(/(\d+.*)\d+/, "$1"+num_replace);
```